# How to attach and get particular list item id in BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I am trying to create lists using FieldManagers (Horizontal and Vertical). In this list I have multiple clickable items like buttons, so I am not using `ListField` or `ObjectListField`.

I have successfully created the UI, but I am unable to attach a particular item id coming from the server.  Also, on clicking a particular button in any list row, I want to get the item id and want to perform an action against that ID.

So, please let me know the idea how I can attach the id to a particular row while I am using FieldManager and then how I can generate event against that ID on clicking a button?

Comment: shall we see what you have tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a row, you are probably creating a (subclass of) `Manager` for each row.

At least, it seems like you are creating a `ButtonField` on each row.

What you can do is to attach a *cookie* to each row, or to each button, when you create it.  A *cookie* is just an extra piece of information that's attached to an object.  Then, when that row or button is clicked, you ask the row/button for the cookie, and use that to identify the row ID.

Every BlackBerry [Field](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#setCookie(java.lang.Object)) can have a cookie attached to it.  Since the cookie is of type `Object`, you can make it anything you want.

For example, when creating the buttons for your rows:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    BitmapButtonField button = new BitmapButtonField(onImage, offImage, ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
    // use the row index as the cookie
    button.setCookie(new Integer(i));
    button.setChangeListener(this);
    Manager row = new MyRowManager();
    row.add(button);
    add(row);
}
```

and then when the button is clicked:

```java
void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
    Object cookie = field.getCookie();
    if (cookie instanceof Integer) {
        Integer rowId = (Integer)cookie;
        System.out.println("Row Id = " + rowId);
    }
}
```

Note: I'm using the BlackBerry Advanced UI [BitmapButtonField](https://github.com/blackberry/Samples-for-Java/blob/master/Advanced%20UI/src/com/samples/toolkit/ui/component/BitmapButtonField.java) for this, but the cookie technique will work with any `Field`, or `Manager` class. [See another example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16072730/119114).